# Search using specific meta fields only (excluding post title and content)

Tags: meta-query

I have a custom post type `my_cpt` with 9 custom meta fields like `first_name, last_name, location, phone, email` etc along with post title and post content.
Now what I want is to search using `first_name` and `last_name` fields only.

See this sample post-

- Post Title: New Player (post title field of WP editor)
- Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit (post content field of WP editor)
- first_name: John (custom meta)
- last_name: Doe (custom meta)
- phone: 123466789 (custom meta)
- email: john@doe.ext (custom meta)
- location: LA (custom meta)

Now if someone searches for

- *Player*, he gets no results.
- *Lorem*, gets no results.
- *John*, he founds this post
- *LA*, gets nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WP_Query` for this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'my_cpt' ) );
```

This will query only posts of the type my_cpt.

To search only for posts with a certain first or last name, you have to extend the query. For this you need to add the field `meta_query`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
                      'post_type' => 'my_cpt' ),
                      'meta_query' => array(
                         'relation' => 'OR', //defaults to AND
                          array(
                             'meta_key' => 'first_name',
                             'meta_value' => $search_string,
                             'compare' => 'LIKE'
                          ),
                          array(
                             'meta_key' => 'last_name',
                             'meta_value' => $search_string,
                             'compare' => 'LIKE'
                          )
                       ));
```

To use this query you probably gonna need a custom search form where you would change the search parameter from `s` to something like `search_my_cpt`.

After you did this you need to edit your `search.php // this is where the results are displayed`:

you need to add something like this:

```
if( isset($_GET['search_my_cpt'])) {
//your new query
//display your search results
}
```

I didnt test this code, but this should bring u very close to what u want to achieve